index entries from front-matter
I am adding an index to a file with book document class with makeidx. The index compiles and prints, but it only includes entries from the main-matter. There are entries from the front-matter, but they do not appear in the printed index or in the .idx file.
From comment:
\documentclass[12pt]{book} %
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel} 
\usepackage{makeidx} 
\makeindex 
\begin{document} 
\frontmatter 
\begin{titlepage} 
\Huge What Better Title? \vspace{300pt} \large 
\begin{flushright} {\sc curtis franks} \end{flushright} 
\end{titlepage} 
\normalsize 
\tableofcontents 
\chapter{Preface} This is a short\index{shortness} preface. 
\mainmatter 
\chapter{The first} This is not only the first but the
 only\index{uniqueness} chapter. 
\backmatter 
\printindex \
end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

I made a short compilable example, and the problem doesn't arise. So I will work up from there and let you know what I discover.

\documentclass[12pt]{book}
%\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\begin{titlepage}
\Huge
What Better Title?
\vspace{300pt}
\large
\begin{flushright} {\sc curtis franks}
\end{flushright}
\end{titlepage}
\normalsize
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Preface}
This is a short\index{shortness} preface.
\mainmatter
\chapter{The first}
This is not only the first but the only\index{uniqueness} chapter.
\backmatter
\printindex
\end{document}

Sorry for the poor formatting in the MWE above. The culprit seems to be the babel package. When I comment out the preamble command where that package is called, as in the posted example, I get two index entries, one from the front-matter and one from the main-matter. But when the package is loaded, I only get the main-matter entry. This somewhat inexplicable phenomenon was not easy to discover!

Please, add the cide to the question
